# On the convergence of the sequence $\,a_n=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{n}{k(n-k)}\right)^{2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let the sequence
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{n}{k(n-k)}\right)^{2}, \quad n\ge 2.
$$
Show that:

A. $\,a_n\le 4$.

B. $\,\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is decreasing, and hence converging.

C. Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

Clearly, B implies A.

The first thing that comes to one's mind is to make $\,\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ look like an approximation of a definite integral. However, we do not have the right power of $n$.

Numerical experiments suggest that $\lim_{n\to\infty}=3.2898\ldots$

Comment: the searched limit is zero and the explicit formula containes the PolyGamma-function

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It is not zero. Just the first term of the sum is larger than 1.

Comment: yes you are right, iit was a typo in my formula

Comment: As an aside, the sequence

$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac1{k^2 (n-k)^2} $$

is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the series expansion of $f(x) = \operatorname{Li}_2(x)^2$, where for $|x| \lt 1$,

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n^2} $$

Note that, when $f$ is analytic, 

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 a_n x^n = \left ( x \frac{d}{dx} \right )^2 f(x) = x^2 f''(x) + x f'(x) = 2 \log ^2(1-x)+\frac{2 x \text{Li}_2(x)}{1-x} $$

To be honest, I am not sure there is much that can be concluded from the sequence based on this result, as the   I just found it interesting.

Comment: @Ron Gordon Interesting comment. Once more, the fascinating function  $Li_2$ is present in computations... even in the background in this case, as you underline it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right)^2 = 2 H_{n-1}^{(2)}+\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right)=2H_{n-1}^{(2)}+\frac{4H_{n-1}}{n}$$
and:
$$ a_{n+1}-a_n = \frac{2}{n^2}+4\left(\frac{H_n}{n+1}-\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}\right)=\frac{6}{n^2}-\frac{4H_n}{n(n+1)}$$
is negative as soon as $4n H_n > 6n+6$. It follows that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 2}$ is a decreasing sequence converging to $2\,\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{3}<\frac{10}{3}$. Here, as usual,
$$ H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k},\qquad H_{n}^{(2)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2} $$
and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $H_n\leq \sqrt{n\,\zeta(2)}$.

Answer (score 8):

Note that $\frac{n}{k(n-k)} = \frac 1k + \frac1{n-k}$, therefore
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac 1k + \frac1{n-k} \right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac 1{k^2} + \frac1{(n-k)^2} +\frac{2}{k(n-k)}\right) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac 1{k^2} + \frac 2n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left(\frac 1k + \frac 1{n-k}\right) = 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac 1{k^2} + \frac 2n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac 1k$$

For the monotonicity of $a_n$ check Jack's answer.

Now observe that the limit of $2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac 1{k^2}$ as $n$ tends to infinity is $2 \cdot \frac {\pi^2}{6} = \frac{\pi^2}{3}$, and the limit of $\frac 2n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac 1k$ is zero. The first limit is well known, for the second you can use e.g. [Stolz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem).

Comment: Simplest answer so far.

Comment: OP asks to show the sequence is decreasing

Comment: Good point, let me edit my answer.

Comment: How about monotonicity of the $\{a_n\}$?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Reference is made to Jack D'Aurizio's answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align} 
a_n= & \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\frac{n}{k(n-k)}\right]^{2} \\ 
= &  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\frac{(n-k)+k}{k(n-k)}\right]^{2} \\
= &  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right]^{2} \\
= &  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\frac{1}{k^{2}}+\frac{1}{(n-k)^{2}}+\frac{2}{k(n-k)}\right] \\
= &  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^{2}}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(n-k)^{2}}+2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)} \\
= &  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^{2}}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(n-k)^{2}}+\frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right] \\
= &  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^{2}}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(n-k)^{2}}+\frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}+\frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-k} \\
\end{align}$$

Now carefully note that the terms in the sum $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^{2}}$ are same as those in $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(n-k)^{2}}$ only in the reverse order. Same also holds for $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k}$ and $\sum_\limits{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n-k}$ .

So we can write that
$$\begin{align} 
a_n= &  \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2}{k^{2}}+\frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2}{k} \\
= & 2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[\frac{1}{k^{2}}+\frac{2}{nk}\right] \\
\end{align}$$

And as $n\to\infty$ , $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^{2}} \to \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{2}{nk} \to 0$.

So the limit of $a_n$ is $\frac{\pi^2}{3}$.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thanks for your help. I have been able to make a conclusion due to it.